# How to make geb throw error when element not found instead of returning EmptyNavigator

Tags: geb

in my page object I have simple method

```
def clickSomething(byName) {    
    $("a.name", text: contains(byName)).click()
}
```

and during execution it does not find required element and goes further.

it happens because, according to documentation, $() returns EmptyNavigator if element not found.

I want for test to fail with some kind of "ElementNotFoundException" or "NullPointerException" on trying to make click on null element.

I also do not want to add additional checks for returned element (because I would need to add that for every element identification).

Is there an elegant workaround for that ?

e.g. for elements declared within "content" there is performed such a check. But what is the best practice for elements found outside content block ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you've encountered which is [`click()` not throwing an error when called on en empty navigator](https://github.com/geb/issues/issues/501) has been [fixed recently](https://github.com/geb/issues/issues/501#event-1280673256) and will be released in the next version of Geb.

If you need to get an error when a selector results in an empty navigator then you can either:

- wrap your selector in a [content definition](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#content-dsl) with the [`required` template option](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#code-required-code) set to true which is the default
- call `verifyNotEmpty()` on your navigator